# Email delivery (or Mailbox) testing without sending emails in PHP?

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, email-validation, email-delivery

I have a list of emails and want to check how many of them are able to receive emails.

I have a PHP code that validates email using

```
filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
```

and

```
$domain = explode('@', $email)[1];
if (!checkdnsrr($domain, 'MX')) {
    return "Domain does not exist or has no MX record";
}
```

But when I check the email `f34f34f34fh34hfh3fhh4hf@gmail.com`, it returns no errors. However the mailbox f34f34f34fh34hfh3fhh4hf does not exist. So sending any emails to this address won't be delivered.

I want to check if the mailbox `f34f34f34fh34hfh3fhh4hf` exists for the domain `$domain` before sending email - without actually sending any emails.

Is it possible with PHP/PHPMailer/SMTP?

A service is doing it already: https://verifalia.com/validate-email

I tried basic validations, but I require a more in-depth email delivery testing approach. First of all to make sure the domain exists and as well as that to ensure the specific mailbox exists.

Comment: If you go to https://verifalia.com/validate-email it gives you a description of how they do it, and also notes that they have an API you can make calls to, if you don't want to re-implement it all yourself. But what they've described in general in their description should be achievable in any programming language

Comment: You could do this by basing code on [the SMTP check example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp_check.phps). This example shows how to connect to a server, authenticate, and disconnect, and you'd just need to add a step to issue a `MAIL FROM` command, then an `RCPT TO` command, and then `QUIT` without actually sending anything. Be warned though, large providers like gmail will consider this spammy behaviour, and may block you from sending altogether. The only reliable way is to send it a real message.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I will look into that and get back to you with what I find.